# Postgres auto increment reseted now saving tries to duplicate primary key

Tags: java, database, postgresql, auto-increment

I have my ID's being generated with a sequence, for three classes that extend one using TABLE_PER_CLASS. This is the superclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documentos")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@IdClass(DocumentoID.class)
public abstract class Documento implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_documento")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "doc_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "doc_seq",
            strategy = "backend.modulos.documentos.DocumentoSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = DocumentoSequenceGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = DocumentoSequenceGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "DOC_"),
                    @Parameter(name = DocumentoSequenceGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")})
    private String idDocumento;
```

My sequence generator is generating ID's like this one: "DOC_00010". And this is working fine, what happened this week was that my database ID increment went back some numbers, we had tons of objects saved in the database, we were at the ID "DOC_00649", but suddenly when we tried to save another document to the database it was returning one "duplicate pkey" error, it was conflicting with the ID "DOC_00194", then trying to save it again, it tried to save to "DOC_00195", we've aready solved the problem by adjusting the value of the increment, but we don't know what could have caused this, any idea?

Comment: what's in DocumentoSequenceGenerator?

Comment: That's the class that is responsible for the style of my ID, it has some methods that generates my ID as "DOC_00000".

Comment: seem the issue is in there, because the issue is about id generation?

Comment: I don't see how my sequence generator can interfere in my database sequence incrementer.

Comment: so the incrementer pure from database? no method there involve sequence then generate?

Comment: Yes, my database incrementer